# What are typical control surface deflection "rate" limits for transport airplanes?

Tags: aircraft-design, control-surfaces, airplane

I was wondering if anyone knows what are some typical control surface/actuator deflection "rate" limits for transport airplanes (i.e. aileron/elevator/rudder deflection rates)? I haven't found any useful information about the deflection rates yet.
Also, are there any ATR-42 500 manuals/references that give control surface deflection limits?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! We have a couple of questions on this already: [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/57091/62), [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/62570/62). Do either of them help?

Comment: @Pondlife, thank you! The links you provided are related to my question, however, I wish the first link would provide any references in regards to the answers.. I am building an aircraft simulation of a transport aircraft (ATR 42) and was trying to set some control surface rate limits... or at least have a ball park from a reference of what those limits could be but haven't found any good reference yet.

Comment: I know flight control systems of the CRJs intimately and I'm not aware of any specifications on the "speed" of surface movement and there is certainly no testing requirement to measure movement rates, only deflection limits.Rates depend on hydraulic power available to push against air loads in response to a rapid control input.With minimal loads, the surface will move as fast as you can move the stick. With high airloads there eventually gets to be a bit of a delay or lag but I've never seen a spec.On CRJ200 there is no rudder limiter req'd because  PCUs can't make full travel at high speed.